How to change the response type in middleware in actix-web?
I'm new to rust and I'm trying to make a middleware to verify JWT
I want Err(actix_web::error::ErrorUnauthorized("Invalid token")) should be a proper http response with json body
I'm not getting where to change the required function signature.
Also, is there a easier and simpler way to implement jwt verification in rust? and should I be using a middleware to do this or I can just create a util function and verify the same on controller? Which way is more preferred and efficient?
use crate::models::user_models::Claims;
use actix_web::{
    dev::{forward_ready, Service, ServiceRequest, ServiceResponse, Transform},
    Error,
};
use dotenv::{dotenv, var};
use jsonwebtoken::{self, decode, errors::ErrorKind, Algorithm, DecodingKey, Validation};
use log::{error, info};
use std::{
    future::{ready, Future, Ready},
    pin::Pin,
};

pub struct JWT;

impl<S, B> Transform<S, ServiceRequest> for JWT
where
    S: Service<ServiceRequest, Response = ServiceResponse<B>, Error = Error>,
    S::Future: 'static,
    B: 'static,
{
    type Response = ServiceResponse<B>;
    type Error = Error;
    type InitError = ();
    type Transform = JWTMiddleware<S>;
    type Future = Ready<Result<Self::Transform, Self::InitError>>;

    fn new_transform(&self, service: S) -> Self::Future {
        ready(Ok(JWTMiddleware { service }))
    }
}

pub struct JWTMiddleware<S> {
    service: S,
}

type LocalBoxFuture<T> = Pin<Box<dyn Future<Output = T> + 'static>>;

impl<S, B> Service<ServiceRequest> for JWTMiddleware<S>
where
    S: Service<ServiceRequest, Response = ServiceResponse<B>, Error = Error>,
    S::Future: 'static,
    B: 'static,
{
    type Response = ServiceResponse<B>;
    type Error = Error;
    type Future = LocalBoxFuture<Result<Self::Response, Self::Error>>;

    forward_ready!(service);

    fn call(&self, req: ServiceRequest) -> Self::Future {
        info!("JWT verification started...");
        let header = req.headers().clone();
        let auth_header = header.get("Authorization");
        let token = match auth_header {
            Some(header_value) => {
                let value_str = header_value.to_str().unwrap_or("");
                if value_str.starts_with("Bearer ") {
                    value_str.trim_start_matches("Bearer ")
                } else {
                    ""
                }
            }
            None => "",
        };

        dotenv().ok();
        let secret_key = var("SECRET_KEY").unwrap();
        let decoding_key = DecodingKey::from_secret(secret_key.as_ref());

        let fut = self.service.call(req);

        match decode::<Claims>(&token, &decoding_key, &Validation::new(Algorithm::HS256)) {
            Ok(_) => {
                Box::pin(async move {
                    let res = fut.await?;
                    Ok(res)
                })
            }
            Err(err) => {
                match err.kind() {
                    ErrorKind::InvalidToken => Box::pin(async move {
                        Err(actix_web::error::ErrorUnauthorized("Invalid token"))
                    }),
                    ErrorKind::ExpiredSignature => Box::pin(async move {
                        Err(actix_web::error::ErrorUnauthorized("Expired token"))
                    }),
                    _ => {
                        Box::pin(
                            async move { Err(actix_web::error::ErrorUnauthorized("Unauthorized")) },
                        )
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

Cargo.toml
[dependencies]
r2d2_sqlite = "0.24.0"
actix-web = "4.5.1"
diesel = { version = "2.1.5", features = [
    "sqlite",
    "r2d2",
    "returning_clauses_for_sqlite_3_35",
] }
diesel_migrations = "2.1.0"
dotenv = "0.15.0"
serde = { version = "1.0", features = ["derive"] }
serde_json = "1.0.114"
env_logger = "0.11.3"
jsonwebtoken = "9.3.0"
bcrypt = "0.15.1"
rand = "0.8.5"
chrono = "0.4.38"
regex = "1.10.4"
futures = "0.3.30"
futures-util = "0.3.30"
log = "0.4.21"


Instead of middleware, I would recommend using FromRequest.   This allows you to create both authenticated and un-authenticated endpoints as specified by the injected parameters to your endpoint. (heavily modified code that wasn't tested, from original production/working code as you did not provide an SSCCE )
e.g.

impl FromRequest for User
{
    type Error = Error;
    type Future = Pin<Box<dyn Future<Output = Result<User, Error>>>>;

    fn from_request(req: &HttpRequest, _: &mut Payload) -> Self::Future {
        let auth_hdr = req.headers().get(AUTHORIZATION).cloned();
        let pool = req.app_data::<Data<DbPool>>().unwrap().get_ref().clone();
        Box::pin(async move {
            match user_from_req(&kc_srvc, auth_hdr, pool).await? {
                Some(user) => Ok(User),
                None => Err(Error::NotAuthenticated("not authenticated".into())),
            }
        })
    }
}

pub enum OptionalRequester {
    Anonymous,
    Authenticated(User),
}

impl FromRequest for OptionalRequester
{
    type Error = Error;
    type Future = Pin<Box<dyn Future<Output = Result<OptionalRequester, Error>>>>;

    fn from_request(req: &HttpRequest, _: &mut Payload) -> Self::Future {
        let auth_hdr = req.headers().get(AUTHORIZATION).cloned();
        let pool = req.app_data::<Data<DbPool>>().unwrap().get_ref().clone();
        Box::pin(async move {
            match user_from_req(&kc_srvc, auth_hdr, pool).await? {
                Some(user) => Ok(OptionalRequester::Authenticated(user)),
                None => Ok(OptionalRequester::Anonymous),
            }
        })
    }
}

This is used like:
// MUST be authenticated
pub async fn get_me(requester: User) -> String {
    Ok(requester.name)
}

// MAY be authenticated
pub async fn get_authenticated(optional_user: OptionalRequester) -> String {
    Ok(match optional_user {
        OptionalRequester::Anonymous => "anonymous".into(),
        OptionalRequester::Authenticated(_) => "authenticated".into(),
    })
}

// authentication IGNORED
pub async fn get_dont_care_about_auth() -> String {
    Ok("maybe you're authenticated, maybe you're not".into())
}


i also tried using actix_web_httpauth, in that too the return type is
Result<ServiceRequest, (Error, ServiceRequest)>
but instead of Error I want a proper HttpResponse
is there any way I can get HttpResponse by using middleware?
or in professional api building too error responses are allowed?

You don't just crash the program.  The Error type is itself convertible to HttpResponse . https://docs.rs/actix-web/latest/actix_web/type.Result.html  You may want to create an Error for your crate that implements actix_web::error::ResponseError.
